# Angular: module lazyLoading and missing chunk

Tags: angular, angular-router

We are using **Lazy Loading** for **Router Modules**.

```
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: 'app/users/users.module#UsersModule',
  },
```

But when we **update version** of our app (upload new bundle to the server) it's always broken: old app (that user has already downloaded) tries to get old chunk file that is not on the server anymore.

**Live example**: https://alexshakura.github.io/chunk-error/
(I've just rename the chunk to highlight the error)

What is the correct way to handle this error?

---

Let me describes the steps:

1. **AppVersion1** is loaded by a user (without lazy loaded chunks)
2. We updated the app and uploaded bundle to the server (so currently **AppVersion2** is correct one)
3. User (who still has **AppVersion1**) goes to route that loads lazy module, **BUT** it tries to load chunk from **AppVersion1** that does not exist anymore.

Comment: What error?  You didn't post one and it isn't clear what you mean by update.  Are you saying that if you recompile and upload that the chunk file is missing?  Or that the manifest isn't pointing to the newest version?

Comment: sorry for being not clear enough. http error of trying to get file (chunk) that does not exist any more (new file has new hash suffix). I'll update question with preview in a bit

Comment: Have you actually verified that the chunk is on the server post upload?  And then have you verified that your manifest matches the supposed chunk? This seems to be a deployment issue based on what you've described so far.

Comment: no, it's outdated application on client side tries to load chunk by old path

Comment: Then you aren't invalidating the client-side cache to properly read from the new manifest.  That or if you are saying that the page is already loaded, you'd have to force a new manifest to each client if you didn't want them to reload.

Comment: David I added live example

Comment: How do you build project? Why i see that name of chunk starts with `a` in your artifacts? https://github.com/alexshakura/chunk-error/blob/gh-pages/a0.65ff86735211bf3ba5a9.chunk.js

Comment: I've updated the description, please look at steps

Comment: So you did it just to show us use case. So you can go with custom error handler to catch such errors or maybe use Service Worker

Comment: yes, custom error handler could be the answer, I just want to check, maybe there is a more precise solution: preloading strategy, interceptor, a routing error

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the ng service worker to do this for you.

The service worker will have its own manifest that will enable the worker to keep track of app versions and cached assets. Every time a user reloads the page, the cached version of the app will be served. Then, in background, the service worker will fetch the current manifest, parse it and if there is a version change, it will cache the new app version in the background. The next user's reload will display the new version of the app.

You can enable the service worker functionality by putting `"serviceWorker": true` to your `.angular-cli.json` into your app section.

Then create a `ngsw-config.json` file in your `src` dir. The defaults should look like this:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

And finally, put NGSW module initialization into your `app.module`:

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    // ...
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Running `ng build --prod` will provide all the rest for you.

You can find more about service workers [in the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2021.

I had the same issueas OP, but I solved it by making it the app a PWA, according to @Heehaaw's tips.

However, I would not recommend @Heehaaws approach for making it an Angular PWA. Instead one should follow Angulars official guide
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Run this command inside your project, or follow the guide above.

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```